# How to close a modal window?

Tags: drupal-8

I've found a few tutorials on how to open a modal window using Drupal 8, not so hard:

```
// Add an AJAX command to open a modal dialog with the form as the content.
    $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand('Load Window', $modal_form, ['width' => '800']));
```

But now how do I programmatically close this window? Or more simply, I would like a "Cancel" button available at the bottom of the modal?

Comment: Its all Jquery UI, https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Ajax%21OpenModalDialogCommand.php/class/OpenModalDialogCommand/8.2.x you can tweek in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but if you make an ajax call to a method that calls the CloseModalDialogCommand() the modal will close.

The route:

```
#Close the modal form
product.closeProductModal:
  path: '/close-modal-form'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\product\Controller\ModalController::closeModalForm'
    _title: 'Close modal'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    _role: 'administrator'
```

And then the controller:

```
Use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CloseModalDialogCommand;
class ModalController extends ControllerBase {
public function closeModalForm(){
        $command = new CloseModalDialogCommand();
        $response = new AjaxResponse();
        $response->addCommand($command);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Best answer mate!

Answer (score 5):

Building on the previous answer, I built a form and added a submit and cancel button like this.  In the module/src/Form/ModalForm.php file the buildform method looks like this:

```
class ModalForm extends FormBase {

 public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $options = NULL) {
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="modal_example_form">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['name'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
      '#size' => 20,
      '#default_value' => 'Joe Blow',
      '#required' => FALSE,
    ];

    $form['email'] = [
      '#type' => 'email',
      '#title' => $this->t('Email'),
      '#size' => 30,
      '#default_value' => 'Joe@Blow.com',
      '#required' => FALSE,
    ];


    $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
    $form['actions']['send'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit me bebe'),
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => [
          'use-ajax',
        ],
      ],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'submitModalFormAjax'],
        'event' => 'click',
      ],
    ];
    $form['actions']['cancel'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('cancel'),
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => [
          'use-ajax',
        ],
      ],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'closeModalForm'],
        'event' => 'click',
      ],
    ];

    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';

    return $form;
  }
```

Here is the submit handler:

```
  /**
   * AJAX callback handler that displays any errors or a success message.
   */
  public function submitModalFormAjax(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();

    // If there are any form errors, re-display the form.
    if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
      $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#modal_example_form', $form));
    }
    else {
      //Close the modal.
      $command = new CloseModalDialogCommand();
      $response->addCommand($command);
    }
    return $response;
  }
```

and the cancel handler

```
  /**
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse
   */
  public function closeModalForm() {
    $command = new CloseModalDialogCommand();
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand($command);
    return $response;
  }
```

Comment: This works and thanks for this; but its slow. It is making an ajax request to the server when all that is needed is to close the modal (client side). Is there a way to add that Cancel button but simply do what the X in the top right corner does (just close the modal with no server calls)?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this question/its answers while researching a similar problem.

IMHO the easiest way is using the Drupal JavaScript dialog API instead of Ajax commands and dedicated server-side callback handlers.

Alter the cancel button as such:

```php
$form['actions']['cancel'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => $this->t('cancel'),
  '#attributes' => [
    'onclick' => "Drupal.dialog(document.getElementById('drupal-modal')).close(); return false;",
  ],
];
```

It will simply close the dialog and prevents any additional requests to the server.